# JavaFX vs Serenity

Tags: javafx, serenity-bdd

I would like to do a small test using JavaFX and Serenity BDD, unfortunately with failure.

-when my code calls manually from the "TestSer" class it works fine.

-when calls from the GUI unfortunately does not work.

It seems to me that I am making a simple mistake with calling this class but I lack this knowledge
I present to you my code and please help.

Test class

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class TestSer extends PageObject {

    public Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Managed
    public WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(id = "b-7")
    private WebElementFacade inputNumber;

    @FindBy(id = "b-8")
    private WebElementFacade buttonCheck;

    @FindBy(id = "b-9")
    private WebElementFacade buttonClean;

    @FindBy(id = "caption2_b-3")
    private WebElementFacade result;

    Page page = new Page();
    String[] arr = {"1230391507", "1230943800","1230705176", "1230943800", "1231069185", "1230500907", "1231079746"};

    @Test
    public  void  dodo() throws Exception {
        page.open();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            page.check( arr[i] );
            System.out.println( arr[i] );
        }
    }

    public void check(String numer)  throws Exception {
        String teraz = Teraz();

        waitFor( inputNumber ).waitUntilEnabled();
        inputNumber.type( numer );
        waitFor( buttonCheck ).isClickable();
        buttonCheck.click();
        this.takeSnapShot(getDriver(), "C:\\Users\\smyha\\OneDrive\\Pulpit\\z\\"+numer+ teraz+  ".png") ;
        waitFor( buttonClean ).isClickable();
        buttonClean.click();
        pause( 2000 );




    }

    public static void takeSnapShot(WebDriver webdriver, String fileWithPath) throws Exception{
        TakesScreenshot scrShot =((TakesScreenshot)webdriver);
        File SrcFile=scrShot.getScreenshotAs( OutputType.FILE);
        File DestFile=new File(fileWithPath);
        FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);
    }

    public void pause(Integer milliseconds){
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(milliseconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String Teraz (){
        Date date = new Date(); //
        SimpleDateFormat hh = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
        SimpleDateFormat mm = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
        SimpleDateFormat ss = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
        String h = hh.format(date);
        String m = mm.format(date);
        String s = ss.format(date);
        String teraz = "_"+h+"_"+m+"_"+s;

        return teraz;
    }
```

Controller class

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    public static final String dane = "1230391507\n" +
            "1230500907\n" +
            "1230705176\n" +
            "1230943800\n" +
            "1231069185\n" +
            "1231079746\n";
    public String [] arr ;
    public String outDir;

    private Window stage;
    public  String dirdir;
    public String[] getArr() {
        return arr;
    }

    public void setArr(String[] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    @FXML
    private JFXTextArea  txtFiield;
    @FXML
    private  JFXTextField txtWhere;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnWhere, btnRun;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        txtFiield.setText( dane );
    }


    public void doWhere(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(stage);

        if(selectedDirectory == null){
        }else{
            txtWhere.setText( selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath() +  "\\");
            dirdir =  selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "\\";
        }
        if (txtFiield.getLength() >0 && txtWhere.getLength() >0){
           // btnWhere.setDisable( false );
            btnRun.setDisable( false );
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void doRun(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        TestSer t = new TestSer();
        t.dodo();
    }
    public void parseField(String wejsciowe){
        setArr( null );
        setArr( wejsciowe.split( "\n" ));
        System.out.println(arr.length);

        String[] a = getArr();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

            if(a[i].length() != 10){
                infoBox( "nieprawidłowa długość NIPu w lini : ", "Niepoprawne dane", "Błąd", i+1 );
            }
        }
    }
public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String headerText, String title, int line){
    Alert alert = new Alert( Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setContentText(infoMessage + line);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setHeaderText(headerText);
    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

}

Errors:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.thucydides.core.util.PropertiesFileLocalPreferences).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.openPageAtUrl(PageObject.java:902)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.open(PageObject.java:803)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.open(PageObject.java:791)
    at com.sub.serenity.TestSer.dodo(TestSer.java:48)
    at com.sub.Controller.doRun(Controller.java:81)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: Given the `NullPointerException` in the `PageObject` for `openPageAtUrl` it seems to me that the PageObject is trying to open a web page using Selenium. I personally haven't tried Serenity with JavaFX yet, but you'll have to use something like [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX) as a bridge.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to search and I took a shortcut. I ran the test from the console.

```
public void cmd(String command) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\" &&" + command);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        builder.start();
    }
```

and...

```
 @Test
    public void doRun(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        infoBox( "Czyszczenie projektu SerenityBDD ", "Krok 1- prosze czekac", "Uwaga", 1);
        cmd("mvn clean");
        infoBox( "Wykonanie testu", "Krok 2 - prosze czekac ", "Uwaga", 2 );
        cmd("mvn clean verify");
    }
```

In this way, at the moment I was able to test correctly, but in a very ugly way